# Replacing a specific destination in a string for another string

Tags: c, replace

This is what I got until now:

```
void insert(char str1[], char str2[], int from, int to)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int location;
    if(strlen(str2) < to-from+1) /* The space to put str2 in is bigger than str2 - or in other words - str2 is smaller than it (as in the statement */
    {
        location = from+strlen(str2)+1; /*the location needed to delete would be location to too because location equals to from added by str2 length (what will be replaced by the next, first loop) */
        j = 0;
        for (i = from ; i < to && j < strlen(str2) ; i++)
        {
            str1[i] = str2[j];
            j++;
        }
        **for(i = location ; i <= to ; i++)
        {
            for(j = i ; j <= strlen(str1) ; j++)
            {
                str1[j] = str1[j+1]; /*every string character from i and above will get the value of the string character above her. if i was 3 then str1[3] will get the value of str1[4] and str1[4] will get the value of str1[5] and so...*/
            }
        }**
    }
    else if(strlen(str2) > to-from+1)
    {
        j = 0;
        for (i = from ; i < to && j < strlen(str2) ; i++)
        {
            str1[i] = str2[j];
            j++;
        }
        for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(str2)-(to-from+1) ; i++)
        {
            for(j = strlen(str1) ; j >= to+i ; j--)
            {
                str1[j] = str1[j-1];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;
        for (i = from ; i < to && j < strlen(str2) ; i++)
        {
            str1[i] = str2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is at the bold part (**) - every other statement works but if the statement it's in is correct it won't work, tested a few times - now I'm sure it's a problem somewhere over there. It's all for a calculator I'm doing and it's recursive so I need to replace the string to solve each run of the function. Can someone notice a problem ? Please help if you can, much appreciated :)

EDIT:
**str1 = the string you want to insert to.
**str2 = the string you want to insert

Comment: Have you stepped through your program, line by line, in a debugger? You're not stepping outside of the bounds of the strings anywhere? You're  not trying to modify literal or otherwise constant strings?

Comment: I did it with a table XD kind of primitive but still, maybe I got it wrong - do you happen to know a debbuger which I can download ?

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of that problematic piece of code ? The first loop copies from str2 to str1, the second loop is supposed to make kind of shift to all the members of str1 starting from position where str2 ended ? why ?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio in Windows, or Xcode on OSX you already have one. If you're using Eclipse it's very likely you have one. Otherwise any Linux distribution (as well as MinGW and Cygwin) comes with or have [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) easily available.

Comment: What does `int from, int to` indicate exactly?

Comment: I'll explain :)
The first loop inserts str2 into str1 in the desired location - but because str2 length is smaller than the space the user wanted to delete (to-from+1 - as in the if statement) you need to supposedly delete everything left of it. if str1 was "I like lemons" and from = 0 and to = 3, and let's say str2 is "h" - you can see I do not use all of the space I have (from 0 to 3). I use some but the user wanted to delete from str1[0] to str1[3] ! and I only replaced str1[0] - now the second loop is supposed to delete str1[1], str1[2], and str1[3]...

Comment: You should add comment before each section of code.

Comment: @self it indicates the spot in the string that the user wants to delete and replace by str2. if str1 is "hello", from = 0 and to = 2, then he wants to delete from str1[0] ('h') to str1[2] ('l') and replace it with what str2 might be

Comment: @hyde i added some right now - I'll add more in about one minute - I just download  the debugger Joachim offered

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how to use it once I downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'location' is where the remainder of str1, *starting at 'to'*, should go. Your current code copies the character at 'location+1' to 'location'.

If you want to do it with for-loops, instead of using memmove, the first part should be something like:

```
    location = from+strlen(str2); /* location where remainder of str1 must be shifted to */
    j = 0;
    for (i = from ; i < to && j < strlen(str2) ; i++)
    {
        str1[i] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    for(i = to ; i <= strlen(str1) ; i++)
    {
        str1[location + i - to] = str1[i]; 
    }
```

You might want to change 'to' to 'to+1', depending on your intentions (should the character at 'to' be deleted or not?).

Comment: Not exactly working - it's giving a better result but it's still not perfect - http://pastebin.com/pYipQmYF .
Here above is a part of the program - a function which fully works but won't print the right result - I tried and saw it working but when it's printing after the "insert" there's still something left. Such as if I try "18+3" it would pring "213" (3 left) - Do you know why ?

Comment: Your calculation of 'location' was wrong (off by one). I changed the code above to fix it. I tested with str1="Miss South-America looks good", str2="Asia", from=5, to=18. The result is "Miss Asia looks good", which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

e.g use memmove

```
#include <string.h>

char *insert(char str1[], char str2[], size_t from, size_t to){
    size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);
    if(from > to)
        to = from;
    if(len1 <= from && len1 <= to){
        return strncpy(str1+len1, str2, len2+1); 
    }
    if(len1 > from && len1 <= to){
        return strncpy(str1+from, str2, len2+1); 
    }
    len1 -= to;//strlen(str + to + 1) + 1('\0')
    memmove(str1 + from + len2, str1 + to + 1, len1);
    strncpy(str1 + from, str2, len2);
    return str1;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention - not allowed to use pointers :(((
That's why I'm troubling with this :P

Comment: @user3220493 ; your code used pointer(str1, str2 and strlen). It is a ridiculous story. You can only give up the use of the standard library.

Comment: Where did it use pointers ? All I see is strings and integers :P

Comment: @user3220493 That would be a good place to try to question(to SO) the array passed to the function is whether pointer if you wonder?

Comment: @user3220493 When you pass array to a function, it degenerates into a pointer. There's very little difference between `void func(int *arg)` and `void func(int arg[])`, other than communicating the intention to a human reading the code later. Which is why you see both `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`: it makes no difference to the caller.

Comment: Think about the fact that writing a buggy program. LOL. Let's use the standard library than writing code that stupid.

Comment: Consider it or can not use the standard library before to come up with complex conditions. You can also use it to rewrite the program is complete using the library.